# How to generate a k-combination in a n-element set in TLA+?

Tags: algorithm, tla+, pluscal

In math, a [k-combination of an n-element set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) is a set of all sets that take k element of the n-element set.

However, how can I compute this in TLA+?

I don't know how to compute `(n, k)`, due to my poor algorithm knowledge.

However, I find an ugly way that can compute `(n, 2)` by using cartesian product.

Suppose the n-element set is `X`, so the following `CombinationSeq2(X)` computes the cartesian product of `X` and `X`. If `X` is `{1, 2}`, then the result is `{<<1,1>>, <<1,2>>, <<2,1>>, <<2,2>>}`, so we must use `s[1] < s[2]` to filter repeated sets, thus yielding the final result `{<<1,2>>}`.

```
CombinationSeq2(X) == {s \in X \X X: s[1] < s[2]}
```

Then I convert inner tuple to set by the following

```
Combination2(X) == { { s[1], s[2] } : s \in CombinationSeq2(X) }
```

However, the above solution is ugly:

1. it do not support arbitrary k.
2. it requires element of the set to have order. However, we don't need order here, telling equal or not is already enough.

I wonder is there any solution to do this? I added algorithm tag to this question because I believe if TLA+ don't support this, there should be some algorithm way to do this. If so, I need an idea here, so I can translate them into TLA+.

Comment: *"it requires element of the set to have order. However, we don't need order here, telling equal or not is already enough."* << Very interesting observation. Every implementation of combinations I've seen implicitly made use of order; however, any order will do, and since the set is finite, you can just arrange its elements into an arbitrary sequence. Indeed it's easier to think about an algorithm to generate the combinations of a finite sequence than the combinations of a finite set.

Comment: I'm not familiar with tla+, but one way is to use a recurrence formula: If S is a set with at least one element and x is a particular element of S, then `Combinations(S, k) = Combinations(S \ {x}, k) union {c union {x} : c in Combinations(S \ {x}, k-1)}` (where `S \ {x}` means "set difference of S and {x}", or equivalently `{y in S: y != x}`)

Comment: @Stef Given the set of `{ Tiger, Cat, Whale }`, the type of the elements in this set don't support ordering which means we can't compare if `Tiger` is bigger than or smaller than `Cat`, but we can know `Tiger` is not equal to `Cat`. I think "not equal" is enough here.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I'm saying is that all algorithms I'm aware of implicitly order the elements anyway, calling x_0 = Tiger, x_1 = Cat, x_2 = Whale, and always returning the combinations respecting that order.

Comment: For instance with the recurrence formula I've given above, if you want to turn it into an actual algorithm, you need a way to select an arbitrary element of a set and remove it; it would actually be easier to write the recurrence for a sequence: calling `Combinations(n, k)` the k-combinations of sequence (x_1, ..., x_n), we get: `Combinations(n, k) = Combinations(n-1, k) union {c union {x_n} : c in Combinations(n-1, k-1)}`

Answer (score 1):

In the [Community Modules](https://github.com/tlaplus/CommunityModules/blob/master/modules/FiniteSetsExt.tla), `kSubset` is defined as

```
kSubset(k, S) == 
   { s \in SUBSET S : Cardinality(s) = k }
```

If done purely in TLA+, this will generate 2^S elements before finding the subsets. The community module also has a Java override to implement the calculation more efficiently. See the [readme](https://github.com/tlaplus/CommunityModules) for instructions on how to use the override.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is not a concern, then something like `{s \in SUBSET X: CARDINALITY s = k}` should be correct.  (I say "something like" because I'm kind of guessing at the syntax.  But `CARDINALITY` is supposed to be in `FiniteSet`.)

All reasonably efficient algorithms that I'm aware of do process the set in some kind of implicit order.

Answer (score -1):

We can generate k-combinations of the given set by writing a recursive function, that takes two parameters, `i`(current position in the set) and `k`(how many elements are left in the current combination). The function returns the set of all combinations that have `k` elements.

```
f(i, k) = {prepend X[i] to all sets returned by f(i + 1, k - 1)} and f(i + 1, k)
f(n + 1, _) = {}
f(_, 0) = {}

Here, '_'(underscore) refers to any possible value.
```

We can get the answer for k-combinations of n-elements set from `f(1, k)`.

Note: As you can see the function works irrespective of the order of the elements in the given set.

I don't know TLA+, but here's an [implementation in C++](https://ideone.com/9WNddC).

Comment: You can't implement the ksubsets this way in TLA+. Sets are unordered and can't be indexed, and recursive solutions are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I did not downvote but I assume it's because a C++ implementation can not be easily translated to TLA+ - one is a programing language, the other is a logic.

Comment: @Hovercouch That's interesting, what operations are allowed on sets? Can I read about them somewhere?

Comment: Hi, I think the intuition of your solution is we can use recursive functions to iterate over all cases that every element of the n-sized set is or is not in this set. I upvoted your question because I am ok with recursive functions here since TLA+ is some kind of declarative IMO in which recursion is quite common. Also, I think there is a Sequence type like `<<1,2,3>>` in TLA+, so maybe we can translate this code into TLA+ by using Sequence and then convert back to Set, like what I do in `Combination2`. However I have not yet actually done this, but maybe it is possible.